# How do I search a string array for a match in C# like in my code

Tags: c#

Is there some way to do the following in C#, but I was looking and .indexOf didnt stick out to me.  Does it exist, or what other method should I be using?

```
string t = "joke";
string sentence = "there is no joke here";
string[] array = sentence.Split(" ".ToCharArray());

//here is the kicker
int count = array.indexOf(t);
return count;
```

This should return 3??

Comment: You want it to be 3 because joke is the 4th word?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about [`Array.IndexOf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eha9t187.aspx)?

```
var index = Array.IndexOf(array, t);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eha9t187.aspx)

```
int count = Array.IndexOf(array, t);
```

Answer (score 1):

Array.IndexOf is static method, so you should use it like this:

```
int count = Array.IndexOf(array, t);
```

Answer (score 0):

this will give the index of element...

```
int keyIndex = array.ToList().FindIndex(w => w=="joke");
```

Comment: Why take the hit of converting it to a list?

Comment: @Hexxagonal - i dont know the direct method so that i foudn this alternet way...........nothing else in it

Comment: what's that? is that a question to me?

Answer (score 0):

```
int indexOfWord = Array.FindIndex(sentence.Split(' '), w => w == t);
```

You don't have to do `Split(" ".ToCharArray())`, because there are `params` keyword in the definition of Split method. Compiler automaticaly converts `Split(' ')` to `Split(new char[] {' '})` for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're close: [Array.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof.aspx) is a static method within Array. So you'd have

```
int index = Array.IndexOf<string>(words, "no");
```

See the difference?